# How can I click one thing that clicks another in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to setup a bit of javascript to detect when the title of an event is clicked and when it is clicked click another link, if that makes sense.

Just realized it would have to click the link within the event card itself.

[Frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ4h3.png)

this is the code I have:

```
var eventTitle = $(".eventCardCnt .title");
var eventMoreInfo = $(".custom_button").find("a");

    eventTitle.click( function(){
       eventMoreInfo.trigger("click");
        //console.log("title clicked");
    });
```

html:

```
        <div class="eventCardCnt eventDisplayCnt  isAnEvent" >
        <div class="cntHolder" >
        <div class="details">
        //  When this is clicked.
        <span class="title">Understanding ‘Prevent Duty’ & Radicalisation</span>
        <div class="dateDetails" style="color:#999999; font-size:14px; line-height:120%;font-weight:normal; padding:3px 0px; padding-bottom:0px;text-align:left; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:0px; border-bottom:0px solid #EEEEEE;">
        <div class="dateCnt">
        <div class="dates">
        <div class="dateWrap">
        <div class="date">Wednesday 10 February 2016</div>
        <div class="time">9:30 am</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <span class="location"><a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=Holiday+Inn,+Camden+Lock,+London" target="_blank">Holiday Inn, Camden Lock, London</a></span>
        <div class="eventDetails">
        <div class="price" >£250.00</div>
        <div class='custom_button'>
        <div class="more_info_button">
        //  Click this link
        <a href="http://carleyconsult.wp.castus1.co.uk/product/understanding-prevent-duty-radicalisation/">More info and book</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

any Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why html code in picture? put your efforts to your question with real code instead of image.

Comment: instead of image of source code.. share the html in the question

Comment: check the sample i made hope this works for you https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/sok1Ldyh/

Comment: I guess you want: `$(this).find('.custom_button a')[0].click();`

Comment: Cheers @A.Wolff worked a charm :)

Comment: its hard to wrap that span in a anchor, better to just drop some javascript there :)))

Answer (score 0):

You can use click event in the heading click event like **$(".link").click();**:

```
$(".header").click(function(){
    $(".link").click();
});
$(".link").click(function(){
    alert("Another link Clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code
**HTML PAGE**

```
<div class="eventCardCnt eventDisplayCnt  isAnEvent" >
        <div class="cntHolder" >
        <div class="details">
        //  When this is clicked.
        <span class="title" onclick="clickhref()" >Understanding ‘Prevent Duty’ & Radicalisation</span>
        <div class="dateDetails" style="color:#999999; font-size:14px; line-height:120%;font-weight:normal; padding:3px 0px; padding-bottom:0px;text-align:left; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:0px; border-bottom:0px solid #EEEEEE;">
        <div class="dateCnt">
        <div class="dates">
        <div class="dateWrap">
        <div class="date">Wednesday 10 February 2016</div>
        <div class="time">9:30 am</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <span class="location"><a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=Holiday+Inn,+Camden+Lock,+London" target="_blank">Holiday Inn, Camden Lock, London</a></span>
        <div class="eventDetails">
        <div class="price" >£250.00</div>
        <div class='custom_button'>
        <div class="more_info_button">
        //  Click this link
        <a id="aclick" href="http://carleyconsult.wp.castus1.co.uk/product/understanding-prevent-duty-radicalisation/">More info and book</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function clickhref()
{
     $("#aclick").click();
}
```